# Using data from one excel worksheet in formulas from another worksheet, then returning specific cell results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel worksheets in the same file, one that has a set of data, while the other worksheet has a column with inputs, a table with formulas that use the inputs and return a specific output.

What I would like to do is to create a formula that inserts the data from the first worksheet into the input columns of the formula worksheet and fetches the resulting data from specific cells on the formula worksheet.

I thought of the brute force way of doing this, by copying the formula worksheet over and over, but I was wondering if there's a better way for me to do this.

Here's a concrete example.

**Values sheet**

```
Company     Cars  Guests   Fuel Total Customers Fuel Per Guest  Total Cost
Company A   1     4        7    "= fx total"    "=per guest fx" "=all costs fx"
Company B   2     5        8    "= fx total"    "=per guest fx" "=all costs fx"
Company C   3     6        9    "= fx total"    "=per guest fx" "=all costs fx"
```

**Formula Sheet**

```
Variables   Inputs                  Formulas                End Result
Cars        "=company a cars"       "=maintenance cost fx"  "=all costs fx"
Guests      "=company a guests"     "=total guests fx"      "=per guest cost fx"
Fuel        "=company a fuel"       "=fuel per customer fx"
```

In this example the data from the Company A row is inserted into the **Formula Sheet** and then the results row of the **Values Sheet** fetches the data from the results cells in the **Formula Sheet** based on the current row's inputs.

I'm not sure how to simplify this description but this is what I'm looking to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm fine with responses that solve this excel as well, I think I should have included excel in the title too.

Comment: That is not how this works.  You need to choose which app you are using.  It specifically states on those tags not to cross post.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, I edited the question to be excel specific and have excel tags then.